# My profile on careers is displayed in mixed languages

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Currently [My Profile](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit) on careers is displayed partly in German and English. I have selected the Language "Deutsch" at the bottom of the page.

I also tried private browsing mode in Chrome and tested it in Internet Explorer. Same behavior.

[image]

Comment: +1 I can repro. It even displays mix content for 'Français' language. Not badly as 'Deutsch'

Comment: That's not a bug, your page is just set to Denglisch!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this! Our latest batch of translations was incorrectly imported into the codebase. We've got a fix going out shortly that should address the bulk of these unlocalized strings.